# wxWidgets painting wxGLCanvas on a wxPanel

Tags: c++, opengl, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am trying to draw my wxGLCanvas in a panel and fill the area of the panel but the result is shown in the image below. I had the OpenGL cube sample running fine but in that example, the wxGLCanvas is parented to a wxFrame. When I try to parent it to a wxPanel, I get a fraction of the panel displaying my wxGLCanvas.

[image]

The red box should fill the panel in the image.
Here is the constructor for my window which creates all of the stuff in the image.

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MainWindow, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(wxID_NEW, MainWindow::OnNewWindow)
EVT_MENU(wxID_CLOSE, MainWindow::OnClose)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

MainWindow::MainWindow()
: wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("OpenGL Project Test"),
wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize)
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

    m_statusBar1 = this->CreateStatusBar( 1, wxST_SIZEGRIP, wxID_ANY );
    m_menubar1 = new wxMenuBar( 0 );
    m_menu1 = new wxMenu();
    m_menubar1->Append( m_menu1, wxT("MyMenu") ); 

    m_menu2 = new wxMenu();
    m_menubar1->Append( m_menu2, wxT("MyMenu") ); 

    m_menu3 = new wxMenu();
    m_menubar1->Append( m_menu3, wxT("MyMenu") ); 

    m_menu4 = new wxMenu();
    m_menubar1->Append( m_menu4, wxT("MyMenu") ); 

    this->SetMenuBar( m_menubar1 );

    m_toolBar4 = this->CreateToolBar( wxTB_HORIZONTAL, wxID_ANY ); 
    m_tool1 = m_toolBar4->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxT("tool"), wxNullBitmap, wxNullBitmap,   wxITEM_NORMAL,  wxEmptyString, wxEmptyString, NULL ); 

    m_toolBar4->Realize(); 

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer1;
    bSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer( wxHORIZONTAL );

    // ######### Here is where I try to set the panel as a parent of MyGLCanvas ##########
    m_panel2 = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,          wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE );
    bSizer1->Add( m_panel2, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );
    MyGLCanvas * glCanvas = new MyGLCanvas(m_panel2);


    m_ribbonBar2 = new wxRibbonBar( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_BAR_FLOW_VERTICAL );
    m_ribbonBar2->SetArtProvider(new wxRibbonDefaultArtProvider); 
    m_ribbonPage8 = new wxRibbonPage( m_ribbonBar2, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonPage") , wxNullBitmap , 0 );
    m_ribbonPage8->SetMinSize( wxSize( 400,400 ) );

    m_ribbonPanel16 = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPage8, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonPanel") ,wxBitmap() , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
    m_ribbonButtonBar7 = new wxRibbonButtonBar( m_ribbonPanel16, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonButtonBar7->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonButton"), wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonPanel17 = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPage8, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonPanel") , wxNullBitmap , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
    m_ribbonToolBar2 = new wxRibbonToolBar( m_ribbonPanel17, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar2->AddTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonPanel18 = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPage8, wxID_ANY, wxT("MyRibbonPanel") , wxNullBitmap , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
    m_ribbonToolBar3 = new wxRibbonToolBar( m_ribbonPanel18, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_ribbonToolBar3->AddDropdownTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar3->AddHybridTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar3->AddHybridTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar3->AddHybridTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonToolBar3->AddDropdownTool( wxID_ANY, wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_QUESTION, wxART_OTHER, wxSize(32, 32)), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonBar2->Realize();

    bSizer1->Add( m_ribbonBar2, 0, wxALL, 5 );


    this->SetSizer( bSizer1 );
    this->Layout();

    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    Show();
```

}

This is the bit thats puzzling me

```
m_panel2 = new wxPanel( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE );
bSizer1->Add( m_panel2, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );
MyGLCanvas * glCanvas = new MyGLCanvas(m_panel2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You never specify how should your `glCanvas` be laid out -- so it isn't. The simplest solution is to use a sizer for the panel and add the canvas to this sizer with proportion 1 and expand flag.